# Export from illustrator to html css

Tags: html, css, linux, adobe, designer

I'm using linux and the designer in the company is using illustrator. My question is, there is some kind of tool(way) to export the ai file to html/css to check is properties (size's, text-family, labels name, distances, etc)?

How do you guys communicate with your designers?

Thank you in advance

Comment: No, not possible. Even if, the code would most likely be aweful.

Comment: Yes it will be. But the idea is not using the code, but check some properties of elements.

Comment: Ok then maybe this might help: http://ai2html.org/ Never tested it, though.

Comment: i already try ai2html, it works for text, but it creates all elements (images, and other objects) to one single image. With that i cannot see the size of a simple box, only paragraphs, text size / color.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Then I'd like to refer to my first comment. I don't know any software that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your time anyway @Thomas.

Comment: Could possible be done from Adobe Illustrator to Adobe Dreamweaver or to Adobe Muse, but the code will be very inefficient. I think there should be some online tutorials where they cover this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: sorry, im new in stack overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but http://ai2html.org/ looks like your solution.

Comment: Defenitly it is something, it works for text, but it creates all elements (images, and other objects) to one single image. With that i cannot see the size of a simple box, only paragraphs, text size / color.